# Exception while fetching JSON response from HTTPS url in Android

Tags: android, json, https

I am getting Json response from HTTPS and getting exception as

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Not trusted server certificate
```

below is my code whether I try with HttpGet or HttpPost I get the exception at the line

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

these are the code below for fetching data from an url.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(urlString);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Hoping to get an answer on this problem. thanks.

Comment: see [this](http://blog.crazybob.org/2010/02/android-trusting-ssl-certificates.html) for making https request using DefaultHttpClient

Comment: not a json response. no stacktrace. your server uses a certificate your device doesn't trust, that's what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

The error means, that the validity of the server certificate cannot be established. There can be several reasons for that, for example that a trusted root certificate is not available.

Can you connect to the page from your browser?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while developing an app for my school. The trick is to create two classes that override certificate verification. One extends `HostnameVerifier` and returns true every time `verify()` is called, like t[this](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/AllVerifier.java). The other `class extends X509TrustManager` and overrides `getAcceptedIssuers()` like [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/LoginIOThread.java).

Then you can set the HttpsURLConnection to accept all certificates using this code

```
 HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new AllVerifier());
 try
  {
   SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
   sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new AllTrustManager() }, null);
   HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory());
     } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

That should do the trick. You can see how I used [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-tjintranet/source/browse/trunk/src/edu/tjhsst/androidIntranet/login/LoginIOThread.java) code here, in the run() method.